# SQL Adapter.Fill(dataTable) fetches wrong rows

Tags: c#, sql, ingres

I've encountered a problem in my class for fetching SQL (Ingres.Client lib) data.

SQL query select works fine in SQL DBA client (VDBA) for Ingres Database. Rows gets fetched just right. But my code return shifted data, wrong rows.

E.g. Im trying to fetch data where the DATE is BETWEEN two dates but it returns data that is clearly outside the select scope.

**SQL CLASS**

```
internal class SQL
{
    private string _connectionString = "REDACTED";



    public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, List<IngresParameter> parameters = null)
    {
        using (var connection = new IngresConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new IngresCommand(query, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var adapter = new IngresDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;


                        var dataTable = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        return dataTable;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // log the error
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
SQL S = new SQL();
            

var query = $"select datanl from REDACTED where datanl between '2023-01-04 00:00:00' and '2023-01-05 00:00:00' and belart = 'A'  and planist = 1 order by datanl asc";

dataTable = S.ExecuteQuery(query);
...
```

**First five rows that VDBA returns:**

```
04.01.2023 00:03:10
04.01.2023 00:03:18
04.01.2023 00:06:23
04.01.2023 00:07:07
04.01.2023 00:08:14
```

**First five rows that app SQL class returns:**

```
04.01.2023 1:06:08
04.01.2023 1:08:31
04.01.2023 1:08:34
04.01.2023 1:08:37
04.01.2023 1:08:42
```

Why does Adapter.Fill(dataTable) return shifted results? It seems that it got "pushed" but why?

I've tried adding the `.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true / false` but neither of them seems to do nothing.

Tried to use `IngresDataReader reader = command.ExecuteQuery();` and then `dataTable.Load(reader);` the result is the same.

I'm really not getting why it acts like this..

EDIT:

Tried to change SQL fetch method to another:

```
public DataTable PullData(string INPUT)
    {
        
        using (IngresConnection I_CON = new IngresConnection())
        {
            using (IngresCommand I_CMD = new IngresCommand())
            {
                //Handle Errors @ Connecting
                try
                {
                    I_CON.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                    I_CMD.Connection = I_CON;
                    I_CMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    I_CMD.CommandText = INPUT;
                    I_CON.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine(INPUT);
                    using (IngresDataReader I_RDR = I_CMD.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var dataTable = new DataTable();
                        while (I_RDR.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(I_RDR.GetValue(0));
                        }

                        dataTable.Load(I_RDR);
                        
                        I_RDR.Close();
                        I_CON.Close();
                        I_CON.Dispose();

                        return dataTable;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception E)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }

        }
        
    }
```

Did not work, returned the same mashup like the previous one

Comment: are you 100% sure you're hitting the right database/server/table here? you'd be amazed how many DB questions I've seen where the answer was "oh, wrong database", "oops, I have a per-run copy of the database in the deploy folder" or "oops I have a table in my own account's schema that is taking precedence over the default schema, but only when logging in as a particular account"

Comment: I'm rock solid sure that I am hitting the right thing here. Double checked database. Copied the SQL query straight from VDBA and it just won't be it. 

I even tried to create a new solution just to test it, but its the same result. I'll try different table if it happens again.

Comment: and you're definitely logged in as the same account in both contexts? i.e. the account you're using in VDBA is the same account you're using in your application?

Comment: Yes, it the only production account I have and I use the same in VBDA interface. 
Tried to fetch different table but it is the same result, wrong data fetched. Seems like the row count is alright but it is shifted like 20 rows down (ordering by date - asc.).

Comment: What is the type of the column? Any chance your DB has fancy logic for dealing with time zones based on client settings? If you ignore the order of rows for a minute, can you at least confirm the tables have the same number of rows, and that the rows in the table can be found in your `DataTable`? Just looking at the first rows doesn't tell the whole story.

Comment: I maybe found the culprit. When I change the where clause to date between '2023-01-04 21:00:00' and '2023-01-05 21:00:00' it suddenly works as I want, it fetches all entries between this date but to 22:00:00. How it that possible?

Comment: If you get data up to 22:00 when you ask for 21:00 this strengthens my theory that time zone shenanigans are involved, where one side thinks in UTC but delivers data with an offset (or vice versa).

Comment: How can I prevent this? Is there any paramater to unify the timezones on both side (my side - client to server)?

Comment: I have no experience with Ingres, so I can't help there. You could [edit] your question with your new findings and hope someone else comes along who does know.

Answer (score 1):

VDBA is picking up your local instance's timezone setting (II_TIMEZONE_NAME).
With .Net connections you set such attributes in the connection string.
The name of the keyword is Timezone or TZ.
If you want to check open the Visual Manager and go to the Parameters tab, or enter

ingprenv II_TIMEZONE_NAME

in an Ingres Command Prompt.

See https://docs.actian.com/actianx/11.2/index.html#page/Connectivity/.NET_Data_Provider_Classes.htm#ww245703 re: connection string keywords.